# Changing a vector in place using its values as indices without violating Rust's borrowing rules

Tags: rust

I'm trying to write a program in Rust that receives a series of numbers as machine code and runs the program the numbers specified.

For example, given 1, 10, 12, 30; The first number is the opcode for add, while the next two are input locations, and the last one is the output location. I have written the code below to achieve this (`cmd` is a vector of numbers and `cursor` starts at 0) :

```
loop {
    match cmd[cursor] {
        1 => {
            cmd[cmd[cursor + 3]] = cmd[cmd[cursor + 1]] + cmd[cmd[cursor + 2]];
            cursor += 4; // Go to the next command
        },
        2 => {
            cmd[cmd[cursor + 3]] = cmd[cmd[cursor + 1]] * cmd[cmd[cursor + 2]];
            cursor += 4;
        },
        99 => {
            println!("Value left at position 0: {}", cmd[0]);
            break;
        }
        _ => {
            panic!("Whoops! A wrong opcode was read.");
        }
    }
}
```

This is the error I get when I compile the code:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `cmd` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
  --> src/main.rs:20:21
   |
20 |                 cmd[cmd[cursor + 3]] = cmd[cmd[cursor + 1]] + cmd[cmd[cursor + 2]];
   |                 ----^^^-------------
   |                 |   |
   |                 |   immutable borrow occurs here
   |                 mutable borrow occurs here
   |                 mutable borrow later used here
```

I know what the error means, but I can't think of a way to keep the nested indexing `cmd[cmd[cursor + 3]]` and fix the borrowing rule violation. I tried making a mutable reference for `cmd` before the loops start and using that in the code, but I still get borrowing errors.

What is the idiomatic way to write this code in Rust?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. In the future, try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!